# Remove a Node from a binary tree

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please help. What is wrong with my remove function below. Cant seem to figure it out

I seem to be getting an error:
The class declaration seems pretty fine. The main issue is to have this remove function to work

```
void binaryTree::Remove(int) {
  if (node != NULL)
  {
     Node* tmptr = node;
     int rootdata = node->data;
     /int rSubtree;
  }
  {
  // Case 0- no child
  if (node->lChild == NULL && node->rChild == NULL)
  {
      node = NULL;
      //parent-            //set the parent of the node to NULL
      delete node;
  }
  // has one child
  else if (node->lChild == NULL && node->rChild != NULL)
  {
      node = node->rChild;
      node->rChild = NULL;
      delete node;
  }

  else if (node->lChild != NULL && node->rChild == NULL)
  {
      node = node->lChild;`enter code here`
      node->lChild = NULL;
      delete node;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you cover what happens if you have 2 child nodes?

Comment: deallocation process should be done backwards, it will avoid errors or working on items that are still needed

Comment: Show the declaration of the `binaryTree` class.

Comment: @Gareth: The Program crashes. Though it builds                       @ buck, I have not covered for the two children cos I can seem to get this one right.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping `node = NULL` with `delete node;` Otherwise you're trying to delete NULL.

Comment: No need to do `node = NULL` at all – unless `node` is a reference, in which case it would actually make sense. Otherwise it doesn’t.